# I can't read from group wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall, facebook-group

I can read users feeds or posts

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts
```

but when I try to reach a groups feed or posts, I can't. I added auth part but it returns empty JSON. From the groups I tried, one was closed and 2 other are open groups.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/228955270470492
```

The above returns this:

```
{
  "id": "228955270470492",
   ...
  "name": "ADI BİLİM",
  "privacy": "OPEN",
  ...
}
```

Requesting this feed

```
https://graph.facebook.com/228955270470492/feed?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAACgceqTZCBg0YA7MifDP02MKVXpZCipHJNHmHqK5OTzDvJaNke2JDxhOxKOTFl6bPOoZCZAdUZAQFFV6lD8GCMTxQHigUQZDZD
```

results in empty:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me, is your access token for a user who's a member of the group?

If not, the group needs to have visiblity `OPEN`. You may also need `user_groups` permission for the user, but I'm guessing you already have that if you're accessing the user's list of groups

Comment: Are you talking about the group I pasted above? If what I'm doing working for you, perhaps it is a kind of update problem of fb.

Answer (score 0):

Even this group is public I need to auth app "read_stream" from extended permissions. Now I can see feeds :)